# Как обрезать путь к файлу?

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная

```
import os
way = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Которая возвращает

```
D:\Project\window\python\test\apps\
C:\Folder\Project\window\python\test2\anon\
I:\Test\Project\Block\image\
D:\Project\windows\python\Project\content\
```

Я хочу обработать ее что бы она мне возвращала

```
D:\Project\
C:\Folder\Project\
I:\Test\Project\
D:\Project\
```

Comment: Используйте `pathlib`

Comment: По какому принципу нужно выделять путь? Чтобы последним элементом было Project?

Comment: @insolor Не совсем скорее первым. в 4 строке Project повторяется дважды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
paths = [
    'D:\\Project\\window\\python\\test\\apps\\',
    'C:\\Folder\\Project\\window\\python\\test2\\anon\\',
    'I:\\Test\\Project\\Block\\image\\',
    'D:\\Project\\windows\\python\\Project\\content\\',
    'D:\\roject\\windows\\python\\froject\\content\\',
]

for path in paths:
    start = path.find('Project\\')
    if start != -1: print(path[:start+8])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
paths = [
    'D:\\Project\\window\\python\\test\\apps\\',
    'C:\\Folder\\Project\\window\\python\\test2\\anon\\',
    'I:\\Test\\Project\\Block\\image\\',
    'D:\\Project\\windows\\python\\Project\\content\\',
    'F:\\PyProject\\windows\\python\\fProject\\content\\',
]

for path in paths:
    start = path.find('\\Project\\')
    if start != -1: print(path[:start+9])
```

Comment: Если будет какой-нибудь PyProject в пути (или любая папка с Project в конце), то будет некорректно срабатывать.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, я обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

```
In [147]: import pathlib

In [148]: path = pathlib.PosixPath("some/very/long/path")

In [149]: list(path.parents)
Out[149]:
[PosixPath('some/very/long'),
 PosixPath('some/very'),
 PosixPath('some'),
 PosixPath('.')]
```

Дальше по индексу выбирайте нужый путь. На Windows вместо `PosixPath` - `WindowsPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий пример с `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

paths = [
    'D:\\Project\\window\\python\\test\\apps\\',
    'C:\\Folder\\Project\\window\\python\\test2\\anon\\',
    'I:\\Test\\Project\\Block\\image\\',
    'D:\\Project\\windows\\python\\Project\\content\\',
    'D:\\roject\\windows\\python\\froject\\content\\',
]


def get_project_root(path_string):
    # pathlib.PureWindowsPath вместо pathlib.Path нужно чтобы
    # пример c Windows-путями работал под Linux
    # Если вашем в скрипте обрабатываются нативные для вашей системы пути,
    # можно использовать просто pathlib.Path
    path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(path_string)

    # Если в пути нет Project, то выходим
    if 'Project' not in path.parts:
        return None

    # Находим, в каком куске пути по счету от начала находится первый Project:
    index = path.parts.index('Project')

    # Берем все части пути до Project включительно, собираем из них новый путь
    return PureWindowsPath(*path.parts[:index+1])


for p in paths:
    print(get_project_root(p))
```

Вывод:

```
D:\Project
D:\Project\windows
D:\Project\windows
D:\Project
None
```

Аналогичная функция, но работающая с путями просто как со строками:

```
def get_project_root(path_string, sep='\\'):
    parts = path_string.split(sep)
    if 'Project' not in parts:
        return None
    index = parts.index('Project')
    return sep.join(parts[:index+1])
```